# Redux store.subscribe() doesn't fire on state changes

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working on the app in which a user can change input values and based on them some calculated values should be produced. In this demo I just have three inputs to fill in (the values of which stored in the array in separate file data.js) and only one is calculated as the average of first three.

The project structure is the following:

**src/index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Block1 from "../components/Block1";
import getStore from "../store";
const store = getStore();

const rootEl = document.getElementById("root");

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<Block1 />, rootEl);
};

render();

store.subscribe(() => {
  render();
  console.log("not working");
});
```

**components/Block1.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import getStore from "../store";
const store = getStore();

function Item(props) {
  return (
    <tr key={props.id}>
      <td>{props.rn}</td>
      <td>{props.name}</td>

      {props.not !== "" ? (
        <td>
          <img src={"img/" + props.not} />
        </td>
      ) : (
        <td />
      )}

      {props.isInput ? (
        <td>
          <input type="text" value={props.val} onChange={props.onChange} />
        </td>
      ) : (
        <td>{props.val}</td> 
      )}

      <td>{props.um}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}

export default class Block1 extends Component {
  renderItem(d) {
    return (
      <Item
        key={d.id}
        id={d.id}
        rn={d.rn}
        name={d.name}
        not={d.not}
        val={d.val}
        um={d.um}
        isInput={d.isInput}
        onChange={e =>
          store.dispatch({
            type: "changeValue",
            payload: {
              id: d.id,
              val: e.target.value
            }        
          })
        }
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Block 1. Initial data for calculation</h2>
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>№</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Notation</th>
              <th>Value</th>
              <th>Unit of measure</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{store.getState().map(d => this.renderItem(d))}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import getData from "../data.js";
const data = getData();
const Parser = require("expr-eval").Parser;

export default (state = data, action) => {
  if (action.type === "changeValue") {
    let changedId = action.payload.id;
    // change value in input
    let data = state.slice();
    let el = data.find(d => d.id === changedId);
    el.val = parseFloat(action.payload.val);

    // find all id to re-calculate
    const toRecalculate = getAllDependentDataId(changedId);

    // recalculation
    toRecalculate.forEach(r => {
      // ... here some calculation logic which gives the result

        let el = data.find(d => d.id === r);
        el.val = Math.round((result + 0.00001) * 100) / 100;

        return data;
    });
  }
  return state;
};
```

**store/index.js**

```
import reducer from "../reducers";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import getData from "../data.js";

export default function getStore() {
  const store = createStore(reducer, getData());
  return store;
}
```

The full example is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/04jk9lop0)

The problem is that by some reason new values are not updated in the UI. The code inside of store.subscribe(...) does not run. However, the state is changing - the values are updated in the array - I checked that with console.log...

Please help me to find out the problem.

Comment: Have you read the redux documentation on usage with React? https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

Comment: not yet, thanks, I'll read and try to do it

Comment: Isn't there a Redux middleware that "connects" the state store to React render lifecycle?  (which basically is exactly what you are trying to do) . You're re-inventing the wheel.  You may be doing it for good reason (i.e. to learn).  That said, to answer your question, perhaps look at the source for `react-redux` https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing actions/action creators, connect ,provider, mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps from redux. If you are just having these 4 values, then I would not use redux and just use local state as a controlled component.

If you are trying to use redux, then I would start here.

https://redux.js.org/basics

---

Here is a quick example solving your avg issue with redux:
https://codesandbox.io/s/422q1znj4w

**components/Block1.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { changeValue, loadData } from "../actions/action";
import getData from "../data";

function Item(props) {
  return (
    <tr key={props.id}>
      <td>{props.rn}</td>
      <td>{props.name}</td>

      {props.not !== "" ? (
        <td>
          <img src={"img/" + props.not} />
        </td>
      ) : (
        <td />
      )}

      {props.isInput ? (
        <td>
          <input type="text" value={props.val} onChange={props.onChange} />
        </td>
      ) : (
        <td>{props.val}</td>
      )}

      <td>{props.um}</td>
    </tr>
  );
}

class Block1 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);   
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.loadData(getData());
  }
  renderItem(d) {
    console.log(d.val);
    return (
      <Item
        key={d.id}
        id={d.id}
        rn={d.rn}
        name={d.name}
        not={d.not}
        val={d.val}
        um={d.um}
        isInput={d.isInput}
        onChange={e =>
          this.props.changeValue({ id: d.id, value: e.target.value })
        }
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Block 1. Initial data for calculation</h2>
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>№</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Notation</th>
              <th>Value</th>
              <th>Unit of measure</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{this.props.data.map(d => this.renderItem(d))}</tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    data: state.data
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    changeValue: item => dispatch(changeValue(item)),
    loadData: data => dispatch(loadData(data))
  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Block1);
```

**actions/action.js**

```
export function changeValue(data) {
  return {
    type: "changeValue",
    data
  };
}

export function loadData(data) {
  return {
    type: "loadData",
    data
  };
}
```

**reducers/data.js**

```
export function data(state = [], action) {
  if (action.type === "loadData") {
    return action.data;
  } else {
    if (action.type === "changeValue") {
      let newState = [...state];
      newState[action.data.id - 1].val = action.data.value;

      let counter = 0;
      let sum = 0;

      for (let input of newState) {
        if (input.isInput) {
          sum += parseInt(input.val);
          counter++;
        }
      }
      newState[state.length - 1].val = sum / counter;
      return newState;
    }
  }
  return state;
}
```

**reducers/rootReducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { data } from "./data";
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  data
});
export default rootReducer;
```

**src/index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import configureStore from "../store";
import Block1 from "../components/Block1";

const store = configureStore();

const rootEl = document.getElementById("root");

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Block1 />
  </Provider>,
  rootEl
);
```

**store/index.js**

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "../reducers/rootReducer";

export default function configureStore() {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  );
}
```

Comment: Your code works well. I changed my code. 
It pretty much looks like your code now (except I use js lib "expr-eval" to parse formula text because in real project I have complex formulas. I changed only one file - reducers/data.js and it doesn't re-render changed values and calculated value. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/6xnm0ryqwz
Can you please have a look ?

Comment: You are modifying newState inside of toRecalculate.forEach but you never return newState outside of the forEach. Returning inside of a forEach  will return to values to the forEach not to the function. I edited your sandbox to return newState after your toRecalculate.

Answer (score 2):

> The subscriptions are snapshotted just before every dispatch() call. If you subscribe or unsubscribe while the listeners are being invoked, this will not have any effect on the dispatch() that is currently in progress. However, the next dispatch() call, whether nested or not, will use a more recent snapshot of the subscription list.

https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener

so once the store is created right after that create a subscription (OR)
Before the dispatch action called.

```
const store = createStore(reducer);

//SUBSCRIBE the state change
store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log(store.getState());
});
//ACTION
store.dispatch({ type: "ADD", val: 1 });
```